# CRF Mallet model file

Tags: mallet, crf

What is model-file when we train CRF Mallet? java -cp   "/home/hough/mallet/class:/home/hough/mallet/lib/mallet-deps.jar"  cc.mallet.fst.SimpleTagger   --train true --model-file nouncrf  sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking where to get it (1) or what's format it's in (2) ?

Answers are:

1. According to [documentation](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/sequences.php) `--model-file` option specifies where file will be written to. So MALLET creates it.
2. It's Java object serialized to binary using standard Java serialization.

Comment: So we don't have to create it. OK. Thanks!